# Symmetry and mirror of inverse FFT

Tags: fft, ifft, symmetry

I am trying to do an inverse FFT to get the real signal from a derived formula which describes the Fourier transformed signal. I am doing this with FFT.

I am fairly new to the theory of FFTs, so my questions may be naive.

Taking a modified equation for greens function for 3D diffusion
\begin{equation}
f(r,t) = \frac{r}{(4\pi D t)^{2/3}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{4Dt}-t/\tau}
\end{equation}
the Fourier transform with my convention (normalization $1/2\pi$ and negative exponent on the reciprocal-to-real transform)
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(q,\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{iq}{-i\omega +Dq^2 + 1/\tau}
\end{equation}

The function $f(r,t)$ is non-continuous and defined for positive values only (it's a radial function on $r$).

Now, when doing the FFT, I have understood that the forward FFT produces a complex conjugate result of positive and negative "frequencies." Therefore, when doing my inverse FFT, I am giving as input both negative and positive values of $q$ and $\omega$, evenly spaced around 0.

My question is, why the result in real space (plotted on $r$ axis) has both positive and negative values, and how to know which one to use?

The picture below shows the output of the FFT algorithm of $\hat{f}(q,\omega)$ as well as the analytical result $f(r,t)$. It is clear that the two peaks from the FFT can both be shifted/mirrored as appropriate to match exactly the analytical result, except for the peaks which I also cannot explain.

[image: FFT and analytical]

In my actual problem, I have a more complicated version of $\hat{f}$ which does not have an analytical expression in real space. This is why I am looking at the reverse FFT only. The FFT output is shown below.

[image: FFT problem]

Obviously there is a problem of some sort on the left peak, which is why I am thinking I need to shift and mirror the peak on the right. But this is all too handwaving for me, so I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: have you performed `fftshift`? Is the spikes centered at DC value (center bin) after `fftshift`?

Comment: There is no fftshift implemented in the library I use (Intel's MKL), but I can achieve the same by multiplying my input by $e^{i\pi n}$. When I do the shifting as explained, the spikes are at the center and maybe 1-2 bins to the left and right.
What does this mean, and what would be the justification for doing that?
The problem is that when doing shifting on figure 2, I get the problematic part (left on the figure) as the positive values, which makes me think I need to do a mirroring as well. Does this make sense?

Comment: the frequency shifting is to center X(f) between [-ftop/2 ftop/2] instead of [0 ftop]. Often when x(t) real only half the samples are considered. But TF(x(t))=X(f) is the entire range of frequency samples, that happen to be repeated. When the signal is complex, just don't mirror anything. The halving of the FFT spectrum of real signal is just a display practice, to show [-f/2 f/2] or just show [0 f/2]. But you start folding samples and cutting spectrum you may end up altering the signal.